# How do I handle broken pagination links for SEO when the number of paginated pages falls?

Tags: seo, links, pagination

Example I have A, B, C page dynamically generated based on the 21 rows

- page A contains 10 rows
- page B contains 10 rows
- page C contains 1 row

Google suggested pagination has been implemented

- page A `<link rel=next href=pageB>`
- page B `<link rel=next href=pageC>`, `<link rel=prev href=pageA>`
- page C `<link rel=prev href=pageB>`

all these pages are indexed by Google and now connected each other.

After some days the total number of rows reduced to 20 instead of 21

so now Page A connected to B and B connected to A. C is not generating any link. However, google already cached the page C and C is accessible as empty page. Now google is treating the page C as independent page and competing with Page A & B.

The question is how can we manage the page C so that we can utilize the benefit of index page. We can say no index but data could be increased as well.

Comment: set only A to index, and every next pagination (B, C, ...Z) to noindex - so you avoid the competition between pagination pages and indexed duplicated content.

Comment: Yes but this is not suggested as other pages may contain valuable info for search engine. Also, then next / prev relationship will be void.

Comment: But content on other pages comes firstly at the first page

Comment: Yes but google may show the other pages in SERP and this is the main goal of next / prev relation for pagination.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to prevent your script from showing a blank page with a "200 OK" status for page numbers beyond the last one.  I think you have two options, and either would work:

- Return a "404 Not Found" error for pagination requests beyond the end.
- Redirect such requests to the first page using a "302 Temporary" or "303 See Other" redirect.

Either way, Google will stop indexing page C next time it crawls it if it has one of these two HTTP status codes. The redirect might be somewhat better for users than an error page.

Comment: I agree with 302 or 303. Thanks for your valuable suggestion.